# Flume collector example from Cloudera's UserGuide does not work as expected

Tags: cloud, flume, garbage

The bit in the UserGuide that shows you how to setup a collector and write to it http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/flume/UserGuide/index.html#_tiering_flume_nodes_agents_and_collectors has this configuration:

```
host : console | agentSink("localhost",35853) ;
collector : collectorSource(35853) | console ;
```

I changed this to:

```
dataSource : console | agentSink("localhost") ;
dataCollector : collectorSource() | console ;
```

I spawned the nodes as:

```
flume node_nowatch -n dataSource
flume node_nowatch -n dataCollector
```

I have tried this on two systems:

1. Cloudera's own demo VM running inside VirtualBox with 2GB RAM.
   It comes with Flume 0.9.4-cdh3u2
2. Ubuntu LTS (Lucid) with the debian package and openJDK (minus any hadoop packages installed) as a VM running inside VirtualBox with 2GB RAM
   Followed the steps here https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Flume+Installation#FlumeInstallation-InstallingtheFlumeRPMorDebianPackages

Here is what I did:

`flume dump 'collectorSource()'` leads to

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 35853
tcp6       0      0 :::35853                :::*                    LISTEN      3520/java
$ ps aux | grep java | grep 3520
1000      3520  0.8  2.3 1050508 44676 pts/0   Sl+  15:38   0:02 java -Dflume.log.dir=/usr/lib/flume/logs -Dflume.log.file=flume.log -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -Dzookeeper.root.logger=ERROR,console -Dwatchdog.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/flume/lib::/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 com.cloudera.flume.agent.FlumeNode -1 -s -n dump -c dump: collectorSource() | console;
```

My assumption is that:

```
flume dump 'collectorSource()'
```

is same as running the config:

```
dump : collectorSource() | console ;
```

and starting the node with

```
flume node -1 -n dump -c "dump: collectorSource() | console;" -s
```

`dataSource : console | agentSink("localhost")` leads to

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 35853
tcp6       0      0 :::35853                :::*                    LISTEN      3520/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:44878         127.0.0.1:35853         ESTABLISHED 3593/java       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:35853         127.0.0.1:44878         ESTABLISHED 3520/java 

$ ps aux | grep java | grep 3593
1000      3593  1.2  3.0 1130956 57644 pts/1   Sl+  15:41   0:07 java -Dflume.log.dir=/usr/lib/flume/logs -Dflume.log.file=flume.log -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -Dzookeeper.root.logger=ERROR,console -Dwatchdog.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/flume/lib::/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 com.cloudera.flume.agent.FlumeNode -n dataSource
```

The observed behaviour **is exactly the same in both** the VirtualBox VMs:

Un-ending flow of this at **dataSource**

```
2011-12-15 15:27:58,253 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
durability.NaiveFileWALManager: File lives in
/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource/writing/20111215-152748172-0500.1116926245855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:27:58,253 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
hdfs.SeqfileEventSink: constructed new seqfile event sink:
file=/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource/writing/20111215-152758253-0500.1127006668855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:27:58,254 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
durability.NaiveFileWALManager: opening log file
20111215-152748172-0500.1116926245855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:27:58,254 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
endtoend.AckListener$Empty: Empty Ack Listener began
20111215-152758253-0500.1127006668855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:27:58,256 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
agent.WALAckManager: Ack for
20111215-152748172-0500.1116926245855.00000034 is queued to be checked
2011-12-15 15:27:58,257 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
durability.WALSource: end of file NaiveFileWALManager
(dir=/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource )
2011-12-15 15:28:07,874 [Heartbeat] INFO agent.WALAckManager:
Retransmitting 20111215-152657736-0500.1066489868855.00000034 after
being stale for 60048ms
2011-12-15 15:28:07,875 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
durability.NaiveFileWALManager: opening log file
20111215-152657736-0500.1066489868855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:28:07,877 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
agent.WALAckManager: Ack for
20111215-152657736-0500.1066489868855.00000034 is queued to be checked
2011-12-15 15:28:07,877 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
durability.WALSource: end of file NaiveFileWALManager
(dir=/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource )
2011-12-15 15:28:08,335 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
hdfs.SeqfileEventSink: closed
/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource/writing/20111215-152758253-0500.1127006668855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:28:08,335 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
endtoend.AckListener$Empty: Empty Ack Listener ended
20111215-152758253-0500.1127006668855.00000034

2011-12-15 15:28:08,335 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
durability.NaiveFileWALManager: File lives in
/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource/writing/20111215-152758253-0500.1127006668855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:28:08,335 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
hdfs.SeqfileEventSink: constructed new seqfile event sink:
file=/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource/writing/20111215-152808335-0500.1137089135855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:28:08,336 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
durability.NaiveFileWALManager: opening log file
20111215-152758253-0500.1127006668855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:28:08,337 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
endtoend.AckListener$Empty: Empty Ack Listener began
20111215-152808335-0500.1137089135855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:28:08,339 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
agent.WALAckManager: Ack for
20111215-152758253-0500.1127006668855.00000034 is queued to be checked
2011-12-15 15:28:08,339 [naive file wal consumer-35] INFO
durability.WALSource: end of file NaiveFileWALManager
(dir=/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource )
2011-12-15 15:28:18,421 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
hdfs.SeqfileEventSink: closed
/tmp/flume-cloudera/agent/dataSource/writing/20111215-152808335-0500.1137089135855.00000034
2011-12-15 15:28:18,421 [Roll-TriggerThread-1] INFO
endtoend.AckListener$Empty: Empty Ack Listener ended
20111215-152808335-0500.1137089135855.00000034

..

2011-12-15 15:35:24,763 [Heartbeat] INFO agent.WALAckManager:
Retransmitting 20111215-152707823-0500.1076576334855.00000034 after
being stale for 60277ms
2011-12-15 15:35:24,763 [Heartbeat] INFO
durability.NaiveFileWALManager: Attempt to retry chunk
'20111215-152707823-0500.1076576334855.00000034'  in LOGGED state.
There is no need for state transition.
```

Un-ending flow of this at **dataCollector**:

```
localhost [INFO Thu Dec 15 15:31:09 EST 2011] {
AckChecksum : (long)1323981059821  (string) ' 4Ck��' (double)6.54133557402E-312 } { AckTag : 20111215-153059819-0500.1308572847855.00000034 } { AckType : end }
```

How do I get the console <-> console communication via collectors working again correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your expected behavior is.

But it looks like you may only be binding to the IPv6 interface. I know in the [Hadoop config](https://github.com/infochimps-cookbooks/hadoop_cluster/blob/master/templates/default/hadoop-env.sh.erb#L41) you have to work around this:

```
# Ubuntu wants us to use IPv6. Hadoop doesn't support that, but nevertheless binds to :::50010. Let's tell it we don't agree.
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

You may need a similar option.  To start with, why not set the hostname and port number explicitly, and then back off each in turn?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to  /usr/lib/flume/bin
- rename the file called : flume-env.sh.template to : flume-env.sh
- add this line at the end of the file :
  `export UOPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
- restart your flume instances

=> you will only listen on IP v4 addresses.